# AngularJS ng-click in <tr> to hide a form

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to hide a form when you click on a tr of a table, using ng-click but when I click on the tr nothing happen,

This is the code i have:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="userf in user | filter:buscador as res">
            <tr ng-click="edit($index);showuser= !showuser; hidefrmusuario = !hidefrmusuario">
                <td>{{ userf.matricula }}</td>
                <td>{{ userf.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ userf.celular }}</td>
                <td>{{ userf.correo }}</td>
            </tr>           
</tbody>
```

Thanks btw

Comment: Please add the corresponding Controller code to the question to make a working example of what you have, this helps the SO community to better answer your question [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the hide to your tr,

```
<tr ng-click="edit($index);showuser= !showuser; hidefrmusuario = !hidefrmusuario" 
    ng-hide="showuser">
```